# Issue with book cover on Ascii-doc pdf

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I've just completed my first ascii-doc book and added a picture as cover. The issue is that, when generating the PDF file, the first Heading found in the book, is printed in the middle of the image cover:

```
:title-logo-image: image:images/cover.jpg[]

= Title of the book
```

I've tried adding page breaks ("<<<") after the :title-logo-image but then the picture is not included at all in the final PDF file.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:
`:front-cover-image: image:images/cover.jpg[`]